# Azure Form Recognizer Custom Model Project Limit

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ocr, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

How many projects can be created using a single account/subscription from **Azure Form Recognizer Studio** using custom model? Is there any limit? Can't find anything on the Microsoft documentation about it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from [Microsoft Learn QA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1037160/azure-form-recognizer-custom-model-project-limit.html), and found that there is no limit on the number of projects, but the maximum number of template models is 5000, and 500 for neural models for the standard package now.